# Acessing forms in libre office

Tags: forms, macros, libreoffice

I cant find anny usefull information online, and anny code i find doesnt seem to work, can annyone give me actual code how to acess forms in libre office ? 
i have been trying for 3 day to get my code to work and everytime i get either error or name doesnt exist ... where do i see the name of my objects ? 
i tried renaming them but it doesnt help . I just need a simple macro, that when i press a button the data from forms gets copied into cells on another sheet. 
Here is the code i have right now :

Sub Main

```
dim Form as object
dim filename as String

  xSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets(0)
  Form=Event.Source.Model.Parent


  oCell = xSheet.getCellByPosition(0,0)
  oCell = Form.getByName("PB1").currentvalue

End Sub
```

Form=Event.Source.Model.Parent <- here is where i get the first error "object variable not set"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the code in an event handler, not `Sub Main`.  Here is a working example:

```vb
Sub ButtonClick(oEvent)
    Dim oForm as Object
    Dim oCell as Object
    Dim filename as String

    xSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets(0)
    oForm = oEvent.Source.Model.Parent
    oTextBox = oForm.getByName("TB1")
    filename = oTextBox.currentvalue()
    oCell = xSheet.getCellByPosition(0,0)
    oCell.setString(filename)
End Sub
```

In my form there is a button named "PB1" and a text box named "TB1".

To get this to work, in form design mode, right click on your button and assign this macro to the "Execute action" event.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, i got it working tho using dialogs but this is usefull too as i will need it later on.